# What does it mean for a distribution to be in $L_2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I am new to Sobolev space and distribution theory. So here is what I know. Distributions are linear functionals on $C_0^\infty$. Let's look at the simplest Sobolev space. $H^1(\Omega)$ is equal to the closure (with respect to $L_2$ norm) of the following set
$$\{f\in C(\Omega): \int (1+|\xi|^2)|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi<\infty\}$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Now there is this claim that $H^1(\Omega)$ is the subspace of $L_2$ such that the distributional derivative is still in $L_2$. I am a little confused about this statement. Since distributional derivative is a distribution, what does it mean for a distribution to be in $L_2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A distribution $\mu$ is said to be in $L_2$ if there exists a function $f \in L_2$ so that for all test functions $\phi$ we have $\mu(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \phi(x) \, dx$.

Comment: I am trying to get a little intuition here. So based on what you said, a lot of distributions are not in $L_2$ since for a general distribution, you are not even lucky enough to get that kind of representation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Are there distributions in $L_2$ with derivatives in $L_2$ that *don't* come from $C^1$ functions?

Comment: @Mike Just take a function in $L_2$ that is not $C$, compactly supported, and total integral zero.  Then take its anti-derivative.  Maybe something like $(1-|x|^{3/4})^+$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thanks - and sorry for asking an unrelated question!